# xcode UIBarButtonItem view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, view, uibarbuttonitem

In my Xcode project I have a view controller class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var refreshButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    var refreshUiButton = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        refreshUiButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "refresh"), for: .normal)
        refreshUiButton.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        refreshUiButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didRefreshClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        refreshButton.customView = refreshUiButton
    }
```

and here what it looks like

[image]

The button covers segmented control in the middle of navigation panel.I have an extension for UIButton, because of it I want to use UIbutton as  a custom view for UIBarButtonItem.

I want it to look like this

[image]

How can I organize that?

Comment: are you using UIRightbar button item ? or not ?

Comment: Yes. the refreshButton is in the right bar. It is seen in the second picture.

Comment: Why you want UIButton in UIBar button any specific reason ?

Comment: Yes, I have an extension for UIButton and I want to view it on the navigation bar

Comment: Okay you need to set refreshUiButton frame relative to UIbarbutton frame.

Comment: I am sorry, but it don't works

Comment: can i see the code where you have set fram for contentView ?

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        refreshUiButton.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: refreshButton.width, height: refreshButton.width)
        refreshUiButton.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        refreshUiButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "refresh"), for: .normal)
        refreshButton.customView = refreshUiButton

Comment: try doing this same work in viewDidLayoutSubViews and with width 50 and hieght 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s seems that your button image has incorrect size. If I right you need sizes according [Human Design](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/custom-icons/). Or you can change tint color for system barButtonItem to black.

Comment: refreshUiButton.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit.    
I think it is no mater what sizes my image have.

Comment: @VahagChakhoyan I just checked it. When I use image 500x76 pixels it's stretched to navigation title. I set less size and it's ok. I suppose UIbarButtonItem take size of customView, and customView take size of it's content. Content of button is image size. So contentMode doesn't effect on anything